# ubuntu 18.04 dell XPS caps lock sticks

Tags: 18.04, dell, xps, capslock

I don't know if this is a hardware or software problem, but with my new Dell XPS 13, I find that the caps-lock sticks in the on position and I can't turn it off.        Is there a way to prevent caps-lock from ever coming on again?    I have the following settings in `gnome-tweaks`:

```
Caps Lock Behavior:Disabled
Ctrl position: Caps-lock as control
```

But neither of these settings prevents caps-lock from being stuck in the on position and forcing default caps-lock behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware could be issue and not the software.  I had a similar problem but couldn't turn `caps on` or `off` when I needed.

So I swapped the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd> keys around. Now I can use my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as normal, I didn't use my <kbd>Esc</kbd> often. This is in the same settings you looked at.

Comment: Maybe you could specify how you swapped the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem constantly occurring on my XPS-15, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and couldn't find answers.
Until a moment ago where I just accidentally discovered that *** NEWS FLASH *** You must have accidentally pressed **Shift-CapsLock**

> Pressing **Shift+CapsLock** will make **CapsLock** stick, and following
>   pressings on CapsLock alone will not toggle it back. Only by
>   repressing **Shift+CapsLock** again **CapsLock** will be toggled off again into its usual behavioral state.

Comment: That doesn't happen on my 2018 XPS 13 running Kubuntu 18.04 LTS with HWE.